# How can I change my callback function to promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

This is my node js callback function, I want to change this functions to promise.

```
service.parseToCsv('resources/' + peopleFileName, (err,people) => {
       if(err){
           res.status(400).send('ERROR TO PARSING CSV PEOPLES');
       } else{
           Entry.insertPeoples(people,(err,results) => {
               if(err){
                   let rmPath = 'resources/' + peopleFileName;
                   fs.unlink(rmPath);
                   res.status(400).send('ERROR TO INSERT PEOPLE DATA IN TO DATABASE');
               } else{
                   service.parseToCsv('resources/' + facilityFileName,(err,facilities) => {
                       if(err){
                           console.log(err);
                           res.status(400).send('ERROR TO PARSING CSV FACILITIES');
                       } else{

                           res.status(200).send(facilities);

                       }
                   })
               }
           });
       }
    });
```

I want to see example code.

Comment: I want to see an attempt at least.

Comment: which function you wan to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming service.parseToCSV and Entry.insertPeople return promises.

```
service.parseToCSV('resources/' + peopleFileName).catch(err => Promise.reject(new Error('PARSING CSV PEOPLES')))
.then(people => {
    return Entry.insertPeople(people).catch(err => Promise.reject(new Error('INSERT PEOPLE DATA IN TO DATABASE')));
})
.then(facilityFileName => {
    return service.parseToCSV('resources/' + facilityFileName).catch(err => Promise.reject(new Error('PARSING CSV FACILITIES')));
})
.then(facilities => {
    res.status(200).send(facilities);
})
.catch(err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send('ERROR TO '+err.message);
});
```

Comment: Uh, but they clearly don't return promises in the OPs example?

Comment: This is horrible promise code and makes absolutely no use of chaining.

Comment: Something more to this effect @bergi?